# Replace text between two symbols with regex

Tags: java, regex, replace, replaceall

This should be simple, but I don't know regex... I've seen many similar questions here but none solve precisely what I want.
I have this string:

```
String s = "randomStuff§dog€randomStuff"; //randomStuff is random letters and numbers, it's not a word
```

and I want to replace dog (it's not always dog, don't include it in the regex) with bird, so the output should be:

```
String s = "randomStuff§bird€randomStuff";
```

What I'm using now is

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\§(.*?)\\€", "bird");
```

but this deletes also the § and € symbols. How to keep those symbols too?

Comment: There is one thing left unclear: what about `random§random2§random3€random4`? And: `a€bc€d§e§h`?

Comment: What? If you're speaking about the chance to have a § symbol inside the randomStuff, no it's not possible in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this lookbehind assertion in your regex:

```
s = s.replaceAll("(?<=§)[^€]*", "bird");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kX0yH2/1)

Comment: Nir Levy answer is better suite for this question. Reason - lookahead/behind check should be avoided if possible as they bring unnecessary code/execution complexity.

Comment: **better suite** is subjective here... Avoiding repetition of `§` and `€` is one good reason to use either lookarounds or captured groups. Performance is other reason as `.*?` performs poorly in bigger texts.

Comment: I might be wrong, but as far as I know .*? should have similar performance compared to [^€]* . I definetely agree that replacing ".*?" with "[^€]*" is a good idea, but this is independent of lookahead/lookbehind.

Comment: With this I get the output randomStuff§dog€bird. It replaces the second randomStuff.

Comment: @Dmitry: Well you are comparing 2 answers so compare it entirely not just one part. Just fyi not just `.*?` is inefficient as compared to `[^€]*`,  `.*?` is erroneous also as it won't match newlines between these 2 symbols.

Comment: @anubhava: yes the input is that. The demo changes output if you change the Flavour on the left. I need the code in Java, maybe regex changes with the programming language?

Comment: It should work in Java, I have provided you a Java code. [You can check this Java demo also](http://ideone.com/rDbKqQ)

Comment: @anubhava: my bad, I was silly enough to not copy it correctly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @anubhava if you just read question carefully you would see this: "randomStuff is random letters and numbers" - so ".*?" is erroneousas to same degree. As for comparing - I still believe that lookahead outweight all other problems.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\§(.*?)\\€", "§bird€");
```

Comment: And such a poor performance. Newline symbols are not considered here, either. Why use lazy dot matching if you need to match some unknown text between two  symbols? A negated character class is the only correct answer, IMHO. Also, these `€` and `§` do not need escaping. Also, why use a capturing group (another overhead) if it is not used later (no backreferences are used in the pattern and replacement)?

Comment: I used this workaround too, but I want a real replacing without discarding the two symbols. :)